# How to read Alert Dialog in separate thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog builder in class. I am setting some message into it which comes from reading a file. Earlier as file text wasn't too large it use to load easily, now since the text has grown more it takes a time to load dialog and blocks UI. How can i run this in thread ?

Edited code :

[image]

```
public class Eula TaskCompleteListner{ {

static interface OnEulaAgreedTo {
        void onEulaAgreedTo();
    }


public static boolean show(final Activity activity,final Context context,final Boolean flag) {
        final Preferences prefs = Preferences.getInstance();
        Log.d(TAG, "insideEula");

if (!prefs.getEulaStatus(context)) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    activity);
            Log.d(TAG, "insideEulaLaunch");
            builder.setTitle(R.string.eula_title);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.eula_accept,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            prefs.setEulaStatus(context, true);
                            if (activity instanceof OnEulaAgreedTo) {
                                ((OnEulaAgreedTo) activity).onEulaAgreedTo();

                            }

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.eula_refuse,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            refuse(activity);

                        }
                    });
            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    refuse(activity);
                }
            });

            MyAsync async= new MyAsync(activity, new TaskCompleteListner() {
            public boolean onComplete(String result) {
                builder.setMessage(data);
                builder.create().show();
                return false;
              }
            }) ; 

            MyAsync async= new MyAsync(this, activity) ; 
            async.excecute(); 

            //builder.setMessage(readEula(activity)); //READING FILE AND SETTING HERE
            //builder.create().show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void refuse(Activity activity) {
        activity.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onComplete(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    builder.setMessage(readEula(activity)); //READING FILE AND SETTING HERE
    builder.create().show();
    return false;
}
```

Async Task Class

```
  public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    public static final String ASSET_EULA = "EULA";
    TaskCompleteListner taskCompleteListner;
    Activity activity;
    public interface TaskCompleteListner{
        public boolean onComplete(String result);

    }

    public MyAsync(TaskCompleteListner taskCompleteListner,Activity activity) {
        this.taskCompleteListner = taskCompleteListner;
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

      String data=(String)readEula(activity);
      return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        taskCompleteListner.onComplete(result);
    }

    private static CharSequence readEula(Activity activity) {  //READING FILE HERE
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(ASSET_EULA)));
                String line;
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(line).append('\n');

                byte[] latin1 = buffer.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                return new String(latin1);

                //return buffer;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "";
            } finally {
                closeStream(in);
            }
        }

        private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: try using a AsyncTask and show the alert dialog  in postExcecute.The asyncTask can be a separate class too ,u just nred to exend AsyncTask

Comment: Async task will be the better approach. Do your background operation (readEula(Activity activity)) in doInBackGround and show dialog in onPostExecute method. That will be the cleaner approach.

Comment: did you try my solution below?

Comment: Yes Azhar i tried. First thing i observed was there was no change in behavior. That delay is still there. Also on click of accept it thrown error...Do you want me to paste the code i tried yours ?

Comment: ok sure. what's the error you getting?

Comment: For delay you can add a progress dialog to let user know, that something is running in background. please see my edit in below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` class, where you read your data in `doInBackground()` return the `CharSequence` and do the dialog.show() in `onPostExecute()`.

EDIT:

heres what you can do,

create a class

```
private static class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,CharSequence > {

    Activity activity;
    ProgressDialog dialog 

    public MyAsyncClass(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setMessage("Reading data");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return readEula(activity);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(CharSequence data) {
        if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                activity);
        Log.d(TAG, "insideEulaLaunch");
        builder.setTitle(R.string.eula_title);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.eula_accept,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        prefs.setEulaStatus(context, true);
                        if (activity instanceof OnEulaAgreedTo) {
                            ((OnEulaAgreedTo) activity).onEulaAgreedTo();

                        }

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.eula_refuse,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        refuse(activity);

                    }
                });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                refuse(activity);
            }
        });

        builder.setMessage(data); 
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

then call this class as,

```
if (!prefs.getEulaStatus(context)) {
    MyAsyncClass myAsyncClass = new MyAsyncClass(activity);
    myAsyncClass.execute();
}
```

**Correction to your Edit:**

1. in your Eula class,
   change this,

   MyAsync async= new MyAsync(activity, new TaskCompleteListner() {
           public boolean onComplete(String result) {
               builder.setMessage(data);
               builder.create().show();
               return false;
             }
           }) ;

   ```
       MyAsync async= new MyAsync(this, activity) ; 
       async.excecute();
   ```

to this,

```
MyAsync async= new MyAsync(activity, new TaskCompleteListner() {
        public boolean onComplete(String result) {
            builder.setMessage(data);
            builder.create().show();
            return false;
          }
        }) ; 

        async.excecute();
```

1. in your Async class,

   change your constructor to,

   public MyAsync(Activity activity, TaskCompleteListner taskCompleteListner) {
       this.taskCompleteListner = taskCompleteListner;
       this.activity=activity;
   }

Comment: But since this is not Activity class where do i call Async Task...as in Activity class we call it in onCreate ?

Comment: You have to call async task where ever you are calling your static show method from Eula class to show alert dialog simple.

Comment: I am sorry i am not getting the solution, if anyone who has tried can show me what changes i need to do in code i posted above...Thanks

Comment: Thanks to Azhar as well for putting time and effort...One more observation i found was Charsequence take a time in loading string from file because of some special characters...

Answer (score 1):

Use this Async Class to get the text

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
TaskCompleteListner taskCompleteListner;
Activity activity;
public interface TaskCompleteListner{
    public boolean onComplete(String result);

}

public MyAsync(TaskCompleteListner taskCompleteListner,Activity activity) {
    this.taskCompleteListner = taskCompleteListner;
    this.activity=activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

  String data=(String) readEula(activity);
    return data;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    taskCompleteListner.onComplete(result);
}

 private static CharSequence readEula(Activity activity) {  //READING FILE HERE
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(ASSET_EULA)));
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line).append('\n');

            byte[] latin1 = buffer.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            return new String(latin1);

            //return buffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
        }
    }

    private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }   
}
}
```

You can use this in your Eula class as follows:

```
if (!prefs.getEulaStatus(context)) {
        MyAsync async= new  MyAsync(activity,new TaskCompleteListner() {

            @Override
            public boolean onComplete(String result) {
                //TODO show your alert dialog here. Result has the string needed
                return false;
            }
        }) ;  


    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are few errors in code, can you please correct them.

Comment: Have you saved the MyAsync class? TaskCompleteListener  is an interface within that class.

Comment: Yes Abhilash...I saved but it is showing error again while calling too

Comment: try using new MyAsync.TaskCompleteListner().Also, use async,excecute(); inorder to run the async task.If this doesnt wrk try implementing the TaskCompleteListner in ur Eula class and create  MyAsync object as  MyAsync async= new  MyAsync(activity,this);

Comment: Abhilash while calling async task, I am getting error : The constructor MyAsync(Activity, new TaskCompleteListner(){}) is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59093/discussion-between-user45678-and-abhilash).

Comment: Thanks to Abhilash for carrying out time and helping in resolving it

Answer (score 0):

Async task will be the better approach. 
1. Do your background operation (readEula(Activity activity)) in doInBackGround and 
2. show dialog in onPostExecute method.

In another approach create thread and do your operation (readEula(act)) in it and use handler to communicate to this thread and show alert dialog in you activity only.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a dialog u need to show, you can use the Activity's following method:

```
public final void runOnUiThread (Runnable action)
```

AsyncTask would be a cleaner approach. However, this will save you the trouble of extra code if you are looking for a quick switch onto the main thread.

Comment: runOnUiThread will again be tagged to main thread only. Here question is like how to run in separate thread.